# Помогите составить команду PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Скопировать в папку backup (которая находится в этой директории) все файлы из текущей директории, чьё название начинается с file_

Answer (score 0):

Создаем каталог backup (-Force создает, даже если такой есть), далее копируем файлы

script.ps1

```
New-Item -Path 'backup' -ItemType Directory -Force
Copy-Item -Path "file_*.*" -Destination backup -Force
```

Для запуска скрипта

1. Запускаем PowerShell с правами администратора
2. Для запуска скрипта нужно понизить уровень безопасности, и выполнить

   set-executionpolicy remotesigned